# como Funciona el metodo AddResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Buenas tardes a todos estoy aprendiendo ASP.NET Core 2.0
Y llegue a una sección donde se crea una clase para usarla de repositorio
"Repositorrio.AddResponse(Objeto Recibido)"

1-) Que función tiene los repositorios para que sirven ?

2-) Que función hace el metodo "AddRespose"() para que sirve?

para que se agrega al archivo Startup en la seccion de "ConfigureServices"

Por favor explicarlo de forma mas simple, vengo de leer la documentación  y sigo sin entender

```
public static class Repository
{
    private static List<Estudiante> responses = new List<Estudiante>();
    public static IEnumerable<Estudiante> Responses
    {
        get
        {
            return responses;
        }
    }
    public static void AddResponse(Estudiante estudiante)
    {
        responses.Add(estudiante);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los repositorios, son el medio por el cual vos vas a obtener / insertar información, puede ser,como en tu ejemplo un `List<T>` definida en el programa, como también puede ser la lógica de conexión a una base de datos, de la cual vos obtendrías, modificarías e insertarías información

Te explico, en el código

```
public static void AddResponse(Estudiante estudiante)
{
     responses.Add(estudiante);
}
```

Lo que estas haciendo es agregar al estudiante que recibís como parámetro a la lista `List<Estudiante>` que declaras arriba.

y en el método

```
public static IEnumerable<Estudiante> Responses
{
    get
    {
        return responses;
    }
}
```

Lo que estas haciendo es devolver la misma lista que mencioné arriba, de esa manera, podrías por ejemplo, recibirla en una vista, para mostrar la información de todos tus estudiantes en una tabla

Cualquier cosa que no entiendas de lo que te digo, no dudes en preguntar en los comentarios

Comment: Gracias por responder de verdad! he leido bastante sobre funciones, clases, herencia, Interfaces, pero no logro entender los iteradores Ienumerable...etc... no entiendo que hace con devolver la lista , como funcioana ?
Que gano con iterar el objeto ? he visto variables de tipo IColleccions en interfaces 
    public interface IOrderRepository {

        IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; }

Comment: Al devolver la lista, vos esa lista que devolviste en el controlador, podes recibirla por ejemplo; en una vista, donde podes mostrar la información que contiene cada uno de los objetos de esa lista, por ejemplo, mostrar una tabla con el detalle de cada uno de tus alumnos